# Provide different alignments to composables within 'Column'

Tags: android, vertical-alignment, android-jetpack-compose

I have a 'Text' and another composable within a Column. I want to put the Text to the top and the layout defined by the composable to the bottom. I am not able to find a way to provide different alignments to the 'elements' within Column, as the alignment/arrangement specified in the 'Modifier' of Column works for all the 'elements' within it. My current code aligns both to the bottom. This is my code:

```
@Composable
fun SignUpDetails(navController: NavController) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "First Screen\n" +
                    "Click me to go to Second Screen",
            color = Color.Green,
            style = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(24.dp)
                .clickable(onClick = {
                    // this will navigate to second screen
                    navController.navigate("second_screen")
                })
        )
        ProgressBar1UI()
    }
}
```

How do I achieve my requirement?

Comment: Can you add some details?  Do you want something like Text <Space>  ProgressBar1UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement#SpaceBetween:androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.HorizontalOrVertical):

> Place children such that they are spaced evenly across the main axis, without free space before the first child or after the last child

Something like:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {

        Text( /*...*/ )
        ProgressBar1UI()
}
```

[image]

Otherwise you can use something different like a `Box` and the [**`Modifier.align`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope#align):

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Text(
         modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
    )

    ProgressBar1UI(Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way you can achieve such behavior (one view top second view bottom) is to add the Spacer component with a weight modifier between items.

```
@Composable
fun Example() {
    Column {
        Text("FirstText")

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        Text("SecondText")
    }
}
```

[image: Example]